# How to automatically run a command at startup as root

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I know that one should never want to do this, but I need to run a command as root at startup. For some reason the driver for my wifi card isnt recognized so to get it up and running I have to run

```
sudo modprobe <drivername>
```

each time i boot.

How do I automate this? I don't think I can add a root command to my bash profile.

Side note: Extra points if you can tell me how to do this in [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I know this answers your problem (rather than the question), but if you want a module to be loaded at startup, simply add it to the file /etc/modules

e.g.

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
<drivername>   <--- **here**
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a user yo run as root without a password and assign the program.

```
username ALL=(ALL:ALL)
```

NOPASSWD:/path/to/command

Replace username and /path/to/ with real values.

Then you can add the program to your startup programs.

Open the Dash type: "Startup Applications"

Now click on Add and give in the command to run that runs application.